# Find and replace character next to for uppercase version in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a situation where I have:

```
@return hello world. 

@return goodbye world.
```

and I'd like to find and replace so these become:

```
@return Hello world.

@return Goodbye world.
```

Is this possible with Visual Studio 2008?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's probably easiest just to create a small console application that takes in the whatever.c file and does it for you.  I don't think the Find & Replace has this kind of functionality.

Comment: Instead of a console app, I would opt for a macro.